# Why will my application not load DLLs on first launch, but fine there after?

Tags: c#, dll, windows-ce, cab

I have created an application for Windows CE for a mobile device. When I debug the application from VS the application loads and runs fine. However when I build a CAB file for the installation it does not. The first time I launch the application after installing it, it throws an "TypeLoadException". However when I try again it works fine.

It throws the error the first time I try to access a DLL from the application.

I would like to post as much code as you guys need, however I'm a bit unsure on what's relevant. Here is the INF file I used to make the CAB file with CABWIZ.exe:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider="Y"
CESignature="$Windows CE$"

[CEStrings]
AppName="ShoePDA"
InstallDir="\Backup\XClient"

[Strings]
Manufacturer="Y"

[CEDevice]
VersionMin=4.0
VersionMax=6.99
BuildMax=0xE0000000

[DefaultInstall]
CEShortcuts=Shortcuts
AddReg=RegKeys
CopyFiles=Files.Common1,Files.Common2,Files.Common3,Files.Common4,Files.Common5,Files.Common6,Files.Common7

[SourceDisksNames]
1=,"Common1",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
2=,"Common2",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
3=,"Common3",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
4=,"Common4",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
5=,"Common5",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
6=,"Common6",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\Lib\"
7=,"Common7",,"C:\Users\akj\Documents\Udvikling\SVN\X\Trunk\ShoePDA2\obj\Release\"

[SourceDisksFiles]
"OpenNETCF.Net.dll"=1
"OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.dll"=2
"OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.dll"=3
"OpenNETCF.dll"=4
"datalogic.device2008.dll"=5
"datalogic.wireless2008.dll"=6
"X.exe"=7

[DestinationDirs]
Shortcuts=0,%CE2%\Start Menu
Files.Common1=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common2=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common3=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common4=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common5=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common6=0,"Backup\XClient"
Files.Common7=0,"Backup\XClient"

[Files.Common1]
"OpenNETCF.Net.dll","OpenNETCF.Net.dll",,0

[Files.Common2]
"OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.dll","OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.dll",,0

[Files.Common3]
"OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.dll","OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.dll",,0

[Files.Common4]
"OpenNETCF.dll","OpenNETCF.dll",,0

[Files.Common5]
"datalogic.device2008.dll","datalogic.device2008.dll",,0

[Files.Common6]
"datalogic.wireless2008.dll","datalogic.wireless2008.dll",,0

[Files.Common7]
"X.exe","X.exe",,0


[Shortcuts]

[RegKeys]
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: so my first question would be.. do the file paths exist exactly the same way that you have them on the target device ? what works on your local will not necessarily work on the target path especially if file paths don't exist.. this is my best guess also this is what else could be going on 
`TypeLoadException is thrown when the common language runtime cannot find the assembly, the type within the assembly, or cannot load the type.`

Comment: The DLLs are put there the same way as VS is doing it. The file paths looks identical from VS and after installing with a CAB file. And the weird part is, it is online the first time I trykt to launch it. If I do it again right after the first time it works.

Comment: that is weird. . there is something different going on just try to add some logging and do reverse process of elimination I think this will help you narrow it down.. it may be tasking from a coding standpoint but in will probably help you narrow down your issue.

Comment: What happens if you warm reset after installing but before you run the program for the first time? Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Same thing. I tried catching the TypeLoadException and then warmboot the device from code. However it just threw the exception on a call to another dll, so not a solution. 

However I did solve it. I updated the API dll I was using.. Very strange in my opinion since there were no troubles when debugging..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very weird error. I solved it by updating the API DLL I was using the the device. Very werid when the error did not happen when debugging.. Oh well, guess it is solved.